# Trying to Mirror Screen on HD TV

Tags: display, hdmi, tv, duplicate

Trying to connect my laptop to an HD tv screen via an HDMI cable. It works for about 5 seconds and then the picture disappears on the tv and it turns black. Not only this but when the screen does show some parts are clipped off from the tv (including the start menu). How do I change the resolution, as under "Display" only one resolution is available for the SAMSUMG tv.
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your screen goes black, but the clipping is due to overscan. Most HD TVs produce a picture which is larger than the displayed area so they don't get a black border when showing normal TV. When using as a monitor, this needs to be adjusted. I use 2 nettop PCs (1 Ubuntu, 1 Debian) with HD TV's as monitors to record and watch TV. The display adapter is NVIDIA which has an application (nvidia-settings) which can change the overscan. Depending on your adapter there should be a similar application to reset it.